# Crop image to exact sub-images

Tags: html, macos, image-processing, imagemagick

I know that with ImageMagick, we can crop an images to its "subimages" (or tiles).

Now, let's say I've got images with a width of 480 pixels (the height is variable).

**Using this command, I'm able to successfully crop it :**

```
convert initial.png -crop 480x300 tiles.png
```

Which results to various `tiles_0.png`, `tiles_1.png`, etc - consisting sub-tiles with 480px width.

However, here's the catch : the command returns all 480x300px tiles (from top to bottom, as they are available), but also returns a last tile, which - pretty obviously - can't be of the same height (it's usually less than 300px).

---

**How could I rephrase the command so that it outputs only the tiles of the exact dimensions given, and not that last one?**

Comment: I don't know (hence comment, not answer) but one workaround may be to crop a copy of the source image to integral multiples of the tile size beforehand.

Comment: Is the vertical size of tiles you specified (300px) a mandatory requirement? For example if original image size is 480x1000 according to your question you want to have 3 tiles 480x300, but would it be acceptable to have 4 tiles 480x250 instead?

Comment: @Andrea Yep, you're right. And nope, I'd just need 3 480x300px tiles (and omit the ones with less height)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick's `fx` function to calculate how much you need to chop off the bottom before you do the tiling. The mod operator, for example, will tell you what is left over when you divide the image height by the tile height (300), like this:

```
# First create an arbitrary image 929 px high
convert -size 480x929 xc:blue initial.png

# Now see what we need to chop off
convert initial.png -format "%[fx:h%300]" info:
29
```

So, we need to remove 29 pixels from the bottom by using this as the parameter for `-chop` and it will get chopped off the bottom if we specify `-gravity south`. This can now all be done in one command as follows:

```
convert initial.png                                           \
   -gravity south                                             \
   -chop 0x$(convert initial.png -format "%[fx:h%300]" info:) \
   -crop 480x300 +repage tile.png
```

which will give you 3 tiles each 300 px high:

```
identify tile*
tile-0.png PNG 480x300 480x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 286B 0.000u 0:00.000
tile-1.png[1] PNG 480x300 480x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 286B 0.000u 0:00.000
tile-2.png[2] PNG 480x300 480x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 286B 0.000u 0:00.000
```